# permission for folder that create with mkdir

Tags: php, windows, mkdir, rmdir

I made a folder in  PHP:

```
mkdir('../gallery/images/G'.$result_gallery,0777,true);
```

inside this folder  are photos that users upload. when I want remove this folder or file
this warning appears:

Warning: rmdir(../gallery/images/G35): Permission denied in ...

my platform is windows and Based on explanations php manual mode is ignored on Windows.
What should I do to solve this problem?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to look at [PHP chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a directory which is not empty or have a sub folder directly using rmdir() use the recursive method  posted by @DaHaKa